# ReactiveCocoa memory leak - CocoaAction of UIButton prevents MVVM object deinitialization

Tags: swift, mvvm, uibutton, reactive-cocoa

I'm using MVVM + ReactiveCocoa.

My code works as expected. Except `ViewModel` object had stayed in 'Debug Memory Graph' when I removed `ViewController` from parent.
`ViewController` deinited, unlike `ViewModel`.

Here is how looks button action in `ViewModel`:

```
var changeStatus: Action<Book.Status, Void, NoError> {
    return Action<Book.Status, Void, NoError> { status -> SignalProducer<Void, NoError> in
        return SignalProducer<Void, NoError> { [weak self] observer, error in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                strongSelf.status.value = status
                observer.sendCompleted()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assigning action to button in `ViewController`:

```
reading.reactive.pressed = CocoaAction(viewModel.changeStatus, input: .reading)
```

`reading` button also stays in memory.

When I commented assigning action to button `ViewModel` successfully deinited. Thus, I came to the conclusion that this is the problem. Is it possible this line keeps strong reference?

Dear community, Is there a way to add button action with ReactiveCocoa so that the `ViewModel` object will be deleted on time?

Comment: That line keeps a strong reference to `viewModel.changeStatus` (not `viewModel` itself), and ought to release that reference when the `reading` button is deinitied. You mentioned that `ViewController` deinited: is `reading` definitely being deinited along with it?

Comment: @jjoelson, good point, `reading` button stays in memory. I will have added this to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. By **lazy** defining your action, you make sure that its closure won't be retained.

```
lazy var changeStatus: Action<Book.Status, Void, NoError> = {
    return Action<Book.Status, Void, NoError> { status -> SignalProducer<Void, NoError> in
        return SignalProducer<Void, NoError> { [weak self] observer, error in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                strongSelf.status.value = status
                observer.sendCompleted()
            }
        }
    }
}()
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. I found my problem, and ReactiveCocoa has nothing to do with memory leaks. 
I added my `ViewController` into another view and has done manipulation with his view layer. I used `view.layer.insertSublayer(viewController.view.layer, above: nextItem.viewController.view.layer)` for changing ordering of layers, but when I replace this on `view.bringSubviewToFront(viewController.view)` problem was solved.